# Get the name of the computer

Tags: powershell, scripting, wildcard

Is there a way to name a `.txt` file output by a script that would be the same name as the computer it was run on? Something along the lines of `%computername%.txt`?

example:

```
[String]$logFile = 'C:\Test\nameofcomputer.txt'
```

Comment: `echo 'foo' >> %COMPUTERNAME%.txt`?

Comment: @MarcB For that to work in PowerShell you'd have to prepend it with a `cmd /c`.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the name of the computer through [`$env:computername`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847808.aspx):

```
$logFile = "C:\Test\$env:computername.txt"
```

Notice though that I surrounded the string with quotation marks `"` rather than apostrophes `'`.  This is so that the variable `$env:computername` gets expanded to the name of the computer.